# Are Scipy operations done row-by-row rather than column-by-column as in Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm a novice at NumPy, SciPy. Previously, I've used Matlab/Octave for a long time.

It seems like `scipy.fftpack.fft` works row-by-row for 2-Dimensional array. For me, it's very confusing, since, with Matlab, such operations were done column-by-column. Are all other operations in scipy also performed in row-by-row?

Could I  perform operations column-by-column in NumPy/SciPy as in Matlab?

Comment: `numpy` arrays are, by default, `C_CONTIGUOUS` - values are stored row by row.  MATLAB is, in `numpy` terms `F_CONTIGUOUS`.  Look for example at the sequence 0:12 and reshape it to (3,4) and observe the layout. But you can specify the `numpy` `order`.  That's related to, but not the same, as the question of which axis a particular operation operates on.  Usually you can specify the axis independent of order.

Comment: I think your question is answered. Could you either accept the answer or write a comment if it does not fully answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

Numpy's `fft()` accepts an "axis" argument, so you can ask for column-wise FFT rather than the default row by row FFT.

E.g., the following returns the 16-point FFT of every column in `x`: (you can specify `None` for the 2nd argument if you don't know the number of rows):

```
 import numpy as np

 x = np.hstack([np.zeros((16,1)), np.ones((16,1))])
 x[0,0] = 1

 f = np.fft.fft(x, 16, 0)
```

The first column of `f` is the FFT of a delta function which is all ones. The second column of `f` is the FFT of a constant sequence which is a delta function in the frequency domain.

Comment: It would also be interesting to know whether defaulting to the 2nd "axis" is a general property of NumPy, or specific to its FFT implementation.

Comment: @A.Donda There's really no single convention. Reductions (e.g. sum, max, mean etc.) are always carried out over all axes by default. In other cases (e.g. `np.cumsum`, `np.repeat`, `np.argsort` etc.) the default is to operate over the flattened array. Sometimes the last axis is used by default (`np.diff`, `np.trapz`), but in other cases the first axis is used (`np.split`, `np.concatenate`). It's a bit of a mess, but I have to say I much prefer the default behaviour for reductions in numpy compared to MATLAB, where you have to do `sum(sum(x))` or `sum(x(:))`.